# RSync Folders - Sync Multiple folders on different servers

Tags: linux, unix, sync, rsync

I have a folder called Test and it has only one file called file1 on four different servers. I want all four folders to be in sync If file1 changes on any of the servers.

Does Rsync support this kind ? If Not, what other options do we have to achieve this ?

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

If using Git is an option, maybe that would be a good way to do it. Set up a server with GitLab, and have them all use it as the remote. After changing the file you can push it to the GitLab server, and let the other servers pull from it.

That way you'll also get versioning on top of it.

With hooks you can automate a lot if it.